# How to run API for DLP scan and save to Bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to write a Java CF HTTP trigger, which accepts dataset/table as parameter and runs a predefined DLP template to provide inspection output which needs to be stored in Bigquery.

Currently none of the sample instructions are using Bigquery as Action ouput.  From what I could gather OutputStorageConfig or StorageConfig needs to be used to set the output action to Bigquery, but I am looking for some code examples.

 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
   static Action createSaveFindingsAction(String datasetId, String tableId, String projectId) {
        return Action.newBuilder()
            .setSaveFindings(
                Action.SaveFindings.newBuilder()
                    .setOutputConfig(
                        OutputStorageConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setTable(
                                BigQueryTable.newBuilder()
                                    .setProjectId(projectId)
                                    .setDatasetId(datasetId)
                                    .setTableId(tableId))))
            .build();
      }

  CreateDlpJobRequest createCloudStorageReq(
      String templateName, CloudStorageOptions cloudStorageOptions) {
    return CreateDlpJobRequest.newBuilder()
        .setParent(PARENT)
        .setInspectJob(
            InspectJobConfig.newBuilder()
                .setInspectTemplateName(templateName)
                .setStorageConfig(
                    StorageConfig.newBuilder().setCloudStorageOptions(cloudStorageOptions))
                .addActions(createSaveFindingsAction(INSPECT_OUTPUT_DATASET, TABLE_ID, PROJECT_ID)))
        .build();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Jordana, this works exactly as expected.